# Adword Script in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I am not able to find Adword API support in Google App Script,I can write adword script from adword account but currently i'm handling multiple account(almost 25) what i have to do is go inside individual account and copy my script in that account and adword script have limitation of maximum 15 script can be run by one user at a time, i want to create database of all account at one place that is possible through adword api in java and other programming languages,but i'm quite familiar with Google App script i want to use Adword API in App Script,how can i use UrlFetch() class of Google App Script to use adword api, so that just by replacing client Id of adword account i can get all data at one place(i have access to all account so no need to change username and password).
Thanks in advance for any help and information!

Comment: I have approved Adword API token.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the main problem is that you want to to basicaly make a "code library?" So reuse the same bits of code between accounts?

One option is to use the Eval function, as detailed in tip 3 of this article: http://www.ppchero.com/tricks-for-running-adwords-scripts-in-multiple-accounts/. A second example of using this same method is here: http://www.freeadwordsscripts.com/2013/10/use-gdrive-to-load-single-adwords.html

You would then upload this into Google Drive, or point this to the location of the Google Script.

Another option, as detailed in the PPC Hero Article, is to use Google Sheets to pass the variables you need from one script to another. Basically, the SpreadsheetApp function works within all AdWords scripts, so you can use this to pass data along from external sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are some example scripts regarding Adwords associated with these posts:
http://searchengineland.com/four-ways-you-can-benefit-by-using-adwords-scripts-145530
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/adwords-analysis-in-google-apps-script.html?m=1

Comment: Hi David,Thank you for reply but these links do not solve my problem i want to write script which can access all account from one place,which is not possible through adword interface for app script, is there any way i can do this from adword script? or google app scripts.