# Is there a way to access the Adwords in Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I have created a Adwords Script and able to run in adwords UI.

```
function getCurrentAccountDetails() {
var currentAccount = AdWordsApp.currentAccount();
Logger.log('Customer ID: ' + currentAccount.getCustomerId() +
   ', Currency Code: ' + currentAccount.getCurrencyCode() +
   ', Timezone: ' + currentAccount.getTimeZone());
var stats = currentAccount.getStatsFor('LAST_MONTH');
Logger.log(stats.getClicks() + ' clicks, ' +
   stats.getImpressions() + ' impressions last month');
}
```

Can I run Adwords scripts in Google App Scripts, since GAS can be published as webapps so that I can give some values on demand to the Adwords Script.

I am getting below error because in GAS no access to AdwordsApp. So is there a way to communicate to Adwords Scripts using App scripts.

```
ReferenceError: "AdWordsApp" is not defined.
```

My Requirement is to create video ads by taking inputs from the user. So for this I didn't found any Adwords API details, so I want to use AdwordsScript to create video ads by taking some parameters( name, video_url etc) from the outside.

Comment: If you check the [Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) Adwords is not mentioned so it's safe to say that is on a domain of its own. Apps Scripts is for G Suite Services. You may also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609843/adword-script-in-google-app-scripts) for additional reference.

Comment: Would this help? https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/apps-scripts-execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any official way. There's no REST API and client libraries only exist for a handful of languages. GAS is not one of them. I was only able to find this NPM package for Node:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/adwords-api

Of course, this won't work with Apps Script, so you'll have to rewrite the code.

Comment: This NPM package integrates with the Ads API, but the Ads API does not provide a method for executing Google Ads Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you can through external API, and using OAuth libraries to connect (already included as libraries in google apps script):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2